# Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(x)=f(x+1) \forall x\in \Bbb R$. Then which of the following is true.

Tags: continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(x)=f(x+1) \forall x\in \Bbb R$. Then

(A) $f$ is not necessarily bounded above.

(B) there exists a unique $x_{0} \in R$ such that $f(x_{0} + \pi) = f(x_{0}).$

(C) there is no $x_{0} \in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x_{0} + \pi)=f(x_{0}).$

(D) there exist infinitely many $x_{0} \in \Bbb  R$ such that $f(x_{0} + \pi) = f(x_{0}).$

I know that every continuous periodic function is bounded above and uniformly continuous
so option (A) is wrong, but can't figure out the other options.

Any hint/solution will be very helpful.

Thank You

Comment: I am pretty sure that, using the Intermediate Value Theorem, one can prove that (D) is correct.

Comment: Hint: the function is periodic, so if there existed $x_0$ described in B then also D, hence $x_0$ is not unique. Result: not B. The choice is between C and D.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted, (A) is not correct. Indeed, the periodicity of $f$ tells us that the image of $f$ is $f([0, 1])$. Since $f$ is continuous and $[0, 1]$ compact, it is bounded.

(B) not correct. If such an $x_0$ existed, then $x_0 + 1$ also satisfies that equation.

(C) not correct. Consider $f \equiv 0$.

(D) correct. By the logic in (B), it suffices to show the existence of a single $x_0$ satisfying $f(x_0) = f(x_0 + \pi)$. To do this, consider the function $g : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $$g(x) := f(x) - f(x + \pi).$$
We wish to show that $g$ has a root, i.e., $g(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0 \in \Bbb R$.
If $g(0) = 0$, then we are done. Suppose that this is not the case.
WLOG, assume that $g(0) < 0$. Thus, we get
$$f(0) < f(\pi).$$

Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$, i.e., the unique number in $[0, 1)$ such that $x - \{x\}$ is an integer.

Since $\pi$ is irrational, the set $\{\{n\pi\} : n \ge 2\}$ (I apologise for the bad notation) is dense in $[0, 1]$. Thus, there exists $n \ge 2$ such that $$f(0) < f(\{n\pi\}) < f(\pi).$$

Since $f$ is periodic with period $1$, we have $f(x) = f(\{x\})$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.
But this means that $$f(0) < f(n\pi) < f(\pi).$$
Thus, for some $k$ between $1$ and $n$, we must have $f(k\pi) > f((k + 1)\pi)$ and thus, $g(k \pi) > 0$.

Applying the intermediate value theorem in $[0, k \pi]$ gives that $g$ has a root there since $g$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

1. The constant function can tell you a lot about the validity of $B$ and $C$.
2. The intermediate value theorem should be helpful with $D$.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but is there any obvious use of IVT to conclude D?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Consider $g(x)=f(x)-f(x+\pi)$. If $f$ is maximal at $x_1$ and minimal at $x_2$, then $g(x_1)\ge 0\ge g(x_2)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Wow. Should make that an answer.